# Any STL data structure like pair that gives three items(types) instead of two?

Tags: c++, data-structures, c++11, std-pair

**Question 1:**

I'm using C++ 11, and I'm learning. I realize I can do this with two pairs:

```
pair<pair<<#class _T1#>, <#class _T2#>>, <#class _T3#>>
```

Is that the best way?

**Question 2:**

If I don't need different types, so same type for two items, is it a waste to use pair, what should I use then? For three items? (again same type)

Comment: std::tuple, http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple

Comment: For same-type, `std::array`.

Comment: For same-type (e.g. @Xeo): Could std::vector be a reasonable alternative?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Use a [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple):

```
std::tuple<_T1, _T2, _T3>
```

Note that `std::tuple`s support an arbitrary amount of types stored in them. Also, to access the elements, you can't do the nice `pair.first`/`pair.second`, you have to use the syntax `std::get<n>(tuple)`, where `n` is the element you want to retrieve.

Comment: @Arch1tect No problem. I'd much rather help you than some day have to deal with `std::pair<std::pair<std::pair<...`

Comment: What if you're stuck using C++98?