# Cant make a vector of fixed size arrays?

Tags: c++

I have this odd problem

```
    vector<unsigned int[3]> tris;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < idx.size() - 2; i++) {
        unsigned int push[] = {idx[i], idx[i+1], idx[i+2]};
        tris.push_back(push); //<- this is where it goes belly up
    }
```

The code piece is supposed to unravel a triangle strip index list into triangle indices but wont compile under vs10. Thoughts?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No, unless you wrap your arrays into a `struct` or use something like `std::array`.

The naked C-style array type is not copyable or assignable, which makes it ineligible to serve as a standard container element.

P.S. It should be noted though that C++11 switched to a more elaborate (per-method) approach to specifying requirements to container element type, instead of the more broad approach used by C++03. The above ineligibility claim is based on C++03. I'm not ready to say that it is so unconditionally true for C++11 as well... But it is certainly true even in C++11 if you insist on using `push_back` in your code.

P.P.S. In C++11 one can probably get away with `std::list` of naked C-style arrays and using `emplace` to construct new elements. But not with `std::vector`.

Comment: This is the better answer, as it concisely points out *why* the example is invalid, not just what to do.

Answer (score 12):

Use `std::vector<std::array<unsigned, 3>>` instead.

Comment: This answer looks like it works, but it doesn't. I mean, it works because it lays out everything in a flat contiguous sequence of bytes. But you cannot do `push_back(arr)` on it and hoping that it will append the new `arr`. But you can use `std::memcpy`.

Comment: In C++11 you can actually write tris.push_back(std::array<unsigned, 3>{idx[i], idx[i+1], idx[i+2]}); Combined with the fact that tris.data() is the equivalent C-style array, makes this choice the closest to the original intention, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C++11 you can use tuples.

```
std::vector < std::tuple< unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int > > tris;
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15734156/846686

A less 'elegant' solution can be a pair of a pair

```
    std::vector < std::pair< unsigned int, std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> > tris;
```

but it may result in a very confused code to read...